# How to restructure a table from 1 Row and Many Columns to Several Rows and a Few Columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Say I have a SQL table that has only 1 row:

```
+----+----+----+------+------+------+-------+
| U1 | U2 | U3 | ACC1 | ACC2 | ACC3 | TOTAL |
+----+----+----+------+------+------+-------+
|  1 |  2 |  4 |   10 |   18 |   17 |    45 |
+----+----+----+------+------+------+-------+
```

The table above consists of the following fields:

1. U1: User ID of 1st user in Triple
2. U2: User ID of 2nd user in Triple
3. U3: User ID of 3rd  user in Triple
4. ACC1: ACC for U1
5. ACC2: ACC for U2
6. ACC3: ACC for U3
7. TOTAL: ACC1 + ACC2 + ACC3

Now, I want this table to be more readable by converting it into the following form.

```
+----+----+
| U  | ACC|  
+----+----+
|  1 | 10 |   
|  2 | 18 |
|  4 | 17 | 
+----+----+
```

How do I do this in MySQL? Does PIVOT/UNPIVOT help? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is `union all`:

```
select u1 as u, acc1 as acc from t
union all
select u2 as u, acc2 as acc from t
union all
select u3 as u, acc3 as acc from t;
```

This does require scanning the table three times.  For one row, that makes no difference at all in terms of performance.

`pivot`/`unpivot` won't help, because MySQL doesn't support it.